# MS Word resize the image relative to the size of the window

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, images

I would like to know if MS Word has a capability of resizing images relative to the window size i.e. when the window of the ms word is small the images will be small too (like thumbnails) and when the windows is resized the size of the pictures will resize accordingly. I tried web view hoping it would work but it doesn't.

there is also an option in layout of the image... size.. but the option of relative size is disabled...

[image]

the question is ... is it possible to use ms word in such manner? if not do you know of any text processor that would accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In View Ribbon, click `Zoom`-> `One Page` or `Page Width`.  This will mode will resize the page and all its contents as the window size changes.  Default mode is 100%, which does not "Squeeze" the page down.

Comment: thanks. that worked well. It seems to be working only in the print layout.